# how to invoke another program and get return value by $?

Tags: c, bash, shell, popen

I am using popen() to invoke another program and want to get its return value by $?

ex:

```
FILE* fd = popen("/usr/local/my_check > /dev/null ; echo $?","r");
int read_num = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), BUFFER_SIZE, fp);
printf("%s\n", buffer);
pclose(fd);
```

but I always get zero in prinf function.

any other way to get return value by $? in c program?

thanks!

here is the correct way to get return code of program:

```
int ret = pclose(fd);
if(WIFEXITED(ret))
  printf("%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(ret));
```

Comment: Try man popen: The pclose() function waits for the associated process to terminate; it returns the exit status of the command, as returned by wait4(2).

Comment: thanks, I realize the whole thing on waitpid()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the exit code with

```
int rc = pclose(fd)
```